# Pasting Images to JEditorpane

Tags: java, html, image, paste, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane that uses text/html so it can display images. I can insert images using my own methods (i.e with a JFileChooser) but when it comes to pasting images, it gets a bit messy. I get a load of div tags and `<!--StartFragment-->`/`<!--EndFragment-->` which I do not want  - I simply need whats inbetween the `<img>` tags! Currently I am just using `DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction();` - I have experiemted with other ways though, no luck!

Any one have the same problem? and / or Know of a working solution?

Thanks in Advance

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help
http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html

All you need is to insert the  tag with proper image reference and place the image in the local cache.

Comment: It may be able to help, but with my knowledge, I don't know how! I need to be able to paste images from the internet without anything else other than the img tag bit, unless there's a code that does it all, I'm not even bothered about pasting local images because I have a file chooser for that!

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrate this? Where do you copy the images?

Comment: In your code just add a DocumentListener and check StackTrace of calls to see initial source of the html pasted in you app. Try to find a way to correct the html or just add a DocumentFilter to correct the text. You know it's hard to help without actual code and working example to reproduce behaviour.